# How can a GPS receiver estimate position faster than the worst case 12.5 min it takes to get ionospheric model parameters?

Tags: gps

Consider a single-frequency GPS receiver. On the legacy L1 C/A signal, the receiver will over the course of an entire navigation message (12.5 min) get the model parameters for the ionospehric propagation delay correction. However, a receiver may lock on to the signal from a satellite at a random point of the navigation message that the satellite is currently transmitting. Potentially, it could be right after the ionospheric model parameters were transmitted, and so the receiver could have to wait worst-case up to 12.5 min to get them. Clearly, this is not how things are working because a receiver will usually provide a PVT solution within seconds. How can it do that if it has not yet received the correction parameters?

Comment: My Garmin regularly takes >10 min before it knows where I am.

Comment: I don't see why the GPS needs ionospheric model parameters to provide a good position estimate. It DOES need to store the ephemeris data, though, to avoid a "cold start" where it knows nothing about the satellites.

Answer (score 7):

The receiver can speed up the acquisition phase by retaining prior information from a previous lock. The key parameter for doing this is typically an estimate of the current time. If it can establish that it has not been long since a previous lock, then the ionospheric correction and ephemeris information stored earlier can be reused without having to download it again. Further, the receiver can make a guess as to its current location (e.g. assume that the receiver hasn't moved far) and hence determine which satellites would currently be visible and focus initial searches on trying to acquire them.

For more sophisticated systems (such as a mobile phone), time, approximate location, ephemeris and correction information can be obtained through the network connection without having to receive if from the satellites.

Comment: For your Google-fu, the term typically used for what mobile phones do, which is to use alternative sources other than the GNSS signal, is *aGPS* (or more generally *aGNSS*) which is variously expanded to *augmented*, *assisted*, or *accelerated* GPS / GNSS. Another trick mobile phones use is to constantly record a) their best estimate at their current location and the error estimate together with b) a list of all the WiFi SSIDs and their signal strength they are detecting and upload this data to the OS provider (Google, Apple, …). From this, the OS provider builds a world-wide database of …

Comment: … every WiFi SSID and its location. The phone can then upload a list of all the WiFi SSIDs and signal strengths and ask for its location. Especially in urban areas, this will give a pretty accurate fix in a very short time without even having to use GNSS at all. At one point, Google was considering doing the same thing with Bluetooth Device Addresses. They also recently added photogrammetry, where you point your phone at some characteristic architectural feature or signs.

Answer (score 3):

One does not need the ionospheric parameters in order to get ~10 or in some cases 5m accuracy. The ionospheric model helps to improve accuracy to below 2m. If your receiver exposes its internal parameters in one way or another, you will know when the ionospheric corrections are used.

On the other hand, the timing data is sent much more often than once in 12 minutes. The period is likely few times a second (I don't have the number at hand). If you have the timing data from 4 satellites and a sufficiently recent almanac, you can calculate your position.

A few days old almanac (from previous receiver use) is pretty good for a first approximation that gets you at the proper side of the road (if you use the receiver for navigation). Starting with more or less actual almanac and a known (to withing seconds) time is known as "hot start" and can be as quick as 1-3 seconds.

Few minutes later an actual almanac, as well as the actual ionospheric data are downloaded. This gradually improves the accuracy.

When using an internet-connected device, the almanac, the ionospheric data, the approximate (from a GPS standpoint) time are all downloaded from the Internet over a much higher bandwidth channel. This takes in general less than a second. In some cases even an approximate location (within ~100m) is deduced from other available sources (cell towers, wifi networks, etc). This speeds up even the "cold" start to the same 1-3 seconds.